# How to fit (linear regression) a ratio of all independent variables?

Tags: r, regression, ecology

I am trying to find the best fit between an species dataset and prevailing climatic conditions, in order to be able to predict the environmental conditions from the species dataset (paleoclimate research).

I have 15 species(sp1-sp15), expressed as relative amounts (some are 0).
I have done some data exploration in excel, and have seen that I get good fits using the ratio  sp2/(sp1+sp2).

I have done multiple linear regression on this dataset, but none give a correlation as good as the ratio I stumbled on. The ultimate goal is of course to test whether this ratio I stumbled upon is yields the best model to explain changes in the climate variable.

I would thus like to create the ratios: `sum(spj)/sum(spj)`, where spj refers to one of the species. Here, both the numerator and denominator can be any possible combination of all species.

Can I generate a formula model to include a ratio? Can I then select the best model using regbsubsets?

**EDIT**
Based on answers below, this will not be possible for all 15 variables. How would it be possibel for 5 variables (I have seen this published before, using R).

**EDIT**
On stackoverflow (where I posted the same question), I got the comment to use the function (I), to write expressions inside formulae. However, if I use

```
leapsMAT<-regsubsets(x1 ~ I(1+ (y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 + y8 + y9 + y10 + y11 + y12+ y13 + y14 +y15 )/(y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 + y8 + y9 + y10 + y11 + y12+ y13 + y14 + y15)), force.in= FTFALSE,nvmax=15,data=my.data, nbest=1)
```

the regsubsets doesn't recognize the variables as variables, of course. How do I implement the I(function), or is there another way to deal with this?

At the moment I have obtained the same linear regression using two methods:

```
library(leaps)
attach(my.data)
FTFALSE<-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
leapsMAT<-regsubsets(x1 ~ 1+ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 + y8 + y9 + y10 + y11 + y12+ y13 + y14 + y15 , force.in= FTFALSE,nvmax=15,data=my.data, nbest=1)
```

And, using a longer method specified here (implemented from somewhere else on the internet):

```
allModelsList <- apply(regMat, 1, function(x) as.formula (paste(c("x1 ~ 1", namevar2[x]),collapse=" + " )))
allModelsList
warnings()

#Calculating the model
my.data
allModelsResults <- lapply(allModelsList, function(x) lm(x, data=my.data))
allModelsResults

dfCoefNum   <- ldply(allModelsResults, function(x) as.data.frame(t(coef(x))))

dfStdErrors <- ldply(allModelsResults, function(x) as.data.frame(t(coef(summary(x))[, "Std. Error"])))


dftValues   <- ldply(allModelsResults, function(x) as.data.frame(t(coef(summary(x))[, "t value"])))

dfpValues   <- ldply(allModelsResults, function(x) as.data.frame(t(coef(summary(x))[, "Pr(>|t|)"]))) 
dfpValues
(warnings)
# rename DFs so we know what the column contains
names(dfStdErrors) <- paste("se", names(dfStdErrors), sep=".")
names(dftValues) <- paste("t", names(dftValues), sep=".")
names(dfpValues) <- paste("p", names(dfpValues), sep=".")

# p-value for overall model fit
calcPval <- function(x){
    fstat <- summary(x)$fstatistic
    pVal <- pf(fstat[1], fstat[2], fstat[3], lower.tail = FALSE)
    return(pVal)
}

# Before creating ONE data frame with all important entries,
# we need to compute some more indices 
NoOfCoef <- unlist(apply(regMat, 1, sum))
R2       <- unlist(lapply(allModelsResults, function(x)
                          summary(x)$r.squared))
    adjR2    <- unlist(lapply(allModelsResults, function(x)
                              summary(x)$adj.r.squared))
RMSE     <- unlist(lapply(allModelsResults, function(x)
                          summary(x)$sigma))
fstats   <- unlist(lapply(allModelsResults, calcPval))



# now we can combine all the data into one data frame
results <- data.frame( model = as.character(allModelsList),
                       NoOfCoef = NoOfCoef,
                       dfCoefNum,
                       dfStdErrors,
                       dftValues,
                       dfpValues,
                       R2 = R2,
                       adjR2 = adjR2,
                       RMSE = RMSE,
                       pF = fstats  )
results[1:20,]
# round the results
results[,-c(1,2)] <- round(results[,-c(1,2)], 3)
results

model.maxRadj<-which(results$adjR2 == max(results$adjR2), arr.ind = TRUE)
maxRadj<-results[model.maxRadj,]
```

Many thanks in advance! Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

> I would thus like to create the ratios: sum(spj)/sum(spj), where spj
>   refers to one of the species. Here, both the numerator and denominator
>   can be any possible combination of all species.

No. You don't want to do this. 15 species may be combined in $2^{15}$ ways. That is in your numerator and denominator. You will then have $2^{30}$ ratios to sort through. That can't be a good strategy.

In addition, your dependent variable is "prevailing environmental conditions", it is unlikely that this is a continuous variable. A single condition *might* be continuous (e.g. temperature, humidity) but over all conditions are not likely to be. Even just combining two conditions yields noncontinuous data: Hot dry, cool wet etc. Therefore, I don't think you want linear regression; you probably want multinomial logistic.

Third, you write

> The ultimate goal is of course to test whether this ratio I stumbled
>   upon is yields the best model to explain changes in the climate
>   variable.

OK, I am not a climate scientist, but the relatively abundance of species cannot explain climate although the reverse is possible. It isn't hot because there are more reptiles; it may be that there are more reptiles because it is hot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You indicate that finding the best ratio is not a good strategy, but is it impossible? I will explore the multinomial logistic option, although our goal is to predict continuous variables.

Comment: It would mean adding $2^{30}$ explanatory variables, which is approximately one bilion ($10^9$) variables. This is to all intends and purposes impossible

Comment: Ok, thank you for this clear answer. Would it be possible for a dataset with less species? I have been searching on this problem for a number of days now, it would be good to learn how to do it, for future reference.

Comment: This technique, examining the correlations of all possible ratios  with an environmental parameter has been published in the palaeoclimate field before, I know of an example with 5 species. Can somebody indicate how I could write a function that could do this?

Comment: What continuous variable do you want to predict?  Also, just because it's published doesn't mean it's a good thing to do. If you generated completely random data, this method would still find highly significant results: It's a way of generating type I errors

Comment: I want to predict mean annual air temperature and soil pH. All previous publications have used ratios (usually constructed by trial and error and based on the attributes of each species, once based on a statistical analysis in R), multiple linear correlation has only been used a couple of times during recent years. I have started of the statistical analysis of my new dataset by applying the methods commonly used in the field. It makes sense to use a ratio as well, it highlights changes in species that are not dominant in numbers (remember, the data is expressed as a relative abundance).

Comment: @Peter Predicting climate really is the name of the game; it is using present relationships between climate and biota to get an equation to use with past biological data. To get climatic estimates before the instrumented record from meteorological data we have to use a proxy of some kind or another.

Comment: @ Nick, that's exactly it! Sometimes species assemblages are used as a whole (fi foraminifera), sometimes relative abundances (fi pollen). Do you have any experience with this kind of ratio-based correlations?

Comment: OIC. yes, that makes sense. But prediction is not the same as causation.

Comment: Sorry, no: my experience when confronted with ratios is to move rapidly away, especially when either or both elements may be zero.